# Is the algebra $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$ a smooth algebra in the sense of algebraic geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

First of all, let me fix some terminology: I will follow the definitions that can be found in the book "Cyclic Homology" of J.L. Loday (second edition) page 102 in the special case of $K$ a field.

Let $S$ be a commutative algebra with unit element. A sequence $(x_{1}, ...,x_{n})$ of elements of $S$ is called regular if multiplication by $x_{i}$ in $S/(x_{1}S+...+x_{i-1}S)$ is injective for every $i=1,...,n$.

A commutative unital algebra $A$ is smooth over a field $K$ if for every maximal ideal $M$ of $A$, the kernel of the localized map 
$$\mu_{M}\colon (A\otimes_{K} A)_{\mu^{-1}(M)}\longrightarrow A_{M}$$ is generated by a regular sequence in $(A\otimes_{K} A)_{\mu^{-1}(M)}$. Here the map $\mu\colon A\otimes A\rightarrow A$ is given by the multiplication: $\mu(a\otimes b)=ab$.

$\mathbf{Question}$: Is the algebra $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$ a smooth algebra in the previous sense ? (Here $M$ is a smooth compact manifold).

I have tried to understand what the kernel is: recalling that every maximal ideal of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$ when $M$ is a compact manifold is of the form
$$M=\{f\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R}) : f(p)= 0\}$$
for a fixed $p\in M$, I have deduced that the kernel is the space generated by the elements of this form:
$$ \frac{f\otimes g}{\sum_\alpha r^{\alpha}\otimes q^{\alpha}} \quad \text{such that} \quad f g \equiv 0 \quad \sum_\alpha r^{\alpha}(p)q^{\alpha}(p)\neq 0. $$

I think that this kernel is even not finitely generated but I can't prove it.